# Having trouble with with understanding what a kindle copy of a book means

Tags: amazon, kindle

I don't understand what a book in kindle format means.  It is listed after the listing of several books in Amazon. Can you please explain?

Comment: Basically, it means that it’s a format used by the Kindle devices/apps. (There is a more technical explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_formats), under **KF8 Amazon Kindle**).

Answer (score 0):

Basically any book you see on amazon that has 
[image]
this means that the books can be used in .KPF format which is used exclusively for kindle products. So the book will get sent to your kindle automatically via the amazon application.
Basically, if you buy that kind of copy of the book you can only use it on your Kindle.

Comment: Not exactly. There are Kindle readers available on several platforms. I can read Kindle books on my Android phone, for instance.